# How to get list of successfull and unsuccessfull assertions in Junit5

Tags: java, junit5

Im creating some unit tests to check if different API working correctly. I want to run multiple single unit tests and end up having a list of working/not working APIs. Currently i learn Junit5 to do so and having hard time to understand how to run all assertions regardless if one fails.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class Junit5Utils {
    @DisplayName("Re-usable test")
    @Test
    void testStrings(String a, String b){
        System.out.println("re-usable test");
        Assertions.assertArrayEquals(a.toCharArray(), b.toCharArray());
    }

    @DisplayName("Re-usable test")
    @Test
    void testDouble(double a, double b){
        System.out.println("re-usable test");
        Assertions.assertEquals(a, b);
    }


    @DisplayName("Re-usable test")
    @Test
    void testFloat(float a, float b){
        System.out.println("re-usable test");
        Assertions.assertEquals(a, b);
    }

        @DisplayName("Re-usable test")
        @Test
        void testInt(int a, int b){
            System.out.println("re-usable test");
            Assertions.assertEquals(a, b);
    }

    @Test
    @Disabled("Disabled Test")
    void disabledTest(){
        System.out.println("Disabled Test");
    }



    }

    public class Junit5Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Junit5Utils testUtils = new Junit5Utils();
            testUtils.disabledTest();
            testUtils.testStrings("asd", "asd");
            testUtils.testStrings("asd", "dsa");
            testUtils.testDouble(2.5,2.5);
            testUtils.testInt(1, 1);
            testUtils.testFloat(2.20f, 2.20f);
        }
        }
```

The expected results would be:
Successful: either nothing or list/array of working APIs based on assertions
Unsuccessful: list/array of not working APIs based on assertions

Actual results is:
Successful: nothing if all successful
Unsuccessful: called assertion until the error

*****UPDATE*****

I have tried out using Junit5 with IDE tools, The behavior is the same. If there is a failed assertion the rest of the assertions are not executed. Is this the default behavior ? Can somehow this be changed? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Remove this main class. All the IDEs and all the build tools allow running JUnit tests.

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to structure your tests. Don't write your own runner in main, depend on the one in your IDE of build tool.

Comment: Most likely i wont have an IDE available when i need the unit tests. Most likely i will have to use them as JAR file or in other way so the question still remains. How to have that list, and how to make Junit5 not stop at the first assertion fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to grab any JUnit or JUnit5 tutorial to learn how the library is supposed to be used.

As soon as you have grasped the basic idea (but not earlier) search for „JUnit5 console runner“ to learn how to run tests without an IDE or build tool around.